# .delay() is not a function in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So far the only library I have imported is d3, and I checked the d3.js file to make sure the function was there. It was.

I'm trying to do the example from the data visualization with D3 and AngularJS book. Here's the code [directly from the book, with comments removed] in question:

```
<svg width="800" height="500"></svg>
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = [];
setInterval(function(){
    if (data.length < 8) {
        data.push(Math.random());
    }
    else {
        data = [];
    }
    draw();
}, 1000);

function draw() {
    var svg = d3.select('svg');

    var circles = svg.selectAll('circle').data(data);

    circles
    .attr('fill', 'orange');

    circles.enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('fill', 'red')
    .attr('r', 40)
    .attr('cx', function(d, i) { return i*100 + 50; })
    .attr('cy', 50);

    circles
    .style('stroke', 'black');

    circles.exit()
    .delay()
    .remove();
}
```

The problem I am having specifically is at

```
circles
.exit()
.delay()
.remove();
```

It says that the delay function "is not a function" even though it is. I tried porting the code exactly from the book into a completely new project, but it doesn't work. (I'm using the chrome browser if that makes a difference).

Thanks

Comment: does the exit function return something that you can call delay on?

Comment: Thanks for answering! Yes, it returns an array. When the array length hits 8, the array becomes an array of circle objects, but until then the only meaningful information the console logs is the length of the array

Comment: @johnny5 No it doesn't. `.exit()` returns a d3 [selection](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections), but `.delay()` is a function of d3 [transitions](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#delay)

Comment: What about doing `.delay().exit().remove()`?

Comment: That works fine, no exceptions, and the array moves along perfectly. As for it being a d3 selection, there's no delay function for a d3 selection, so that makes me wonder why the author chose to use the delay function in the book.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

`delay()` is not a function of `selections`. You can call `delay()` for transitions, however. So :

```
circles
  .exit()
  .transition()
  .delay()
  .remove();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately that gives its own fair share of errors, but I've learned that delay can only be called for d3 transition, not d3 selection.